# Setting different axis range for seaborn PairGrid

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting using `seaborn` and I am using `seaborn.PairGrid` function. This is creating 6 x 6 grid, where diagonal plots are histograms and off diagonal plots are scatter plots. Now I want to have different y ranges for each row of plots and different x ranges for each column of the plots. I searched stack exchange a lot but could not find a way to achieve this. Matplot version is `2.0.0` and `seaborn` version is `0.7.1`.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `Axes.set_xlim()` and `Axes.set_ylim()` methods on the axes of the seaborn `PairGrid` or `FacetGrid`. The axes are available from the `PairGrid` as `.axes` attribute.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
g = g.map_diag(plt.hist, edgecolor="k")
g = g.map_offdiag(plt.scatter, s=10)

g.axes[2,0].set_ylim(-10,10)
g.axes[0,1].set_xlim(-40,10)

plt.show()
```