# How to use seaborn kdeplot legend from one suplots axis for whole figure legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using seaborn to plot kdeplots on axes of subplots, and I want to have one global figure legend instead of one legend on each subplot.

However, the axes I pass to `sns.kdeplot` or get from `sns.kdeplot` seem to have empty lists of handles and labels when I use `get_legend_handles_labels()` to get them.

I cannot rely on the data to create a legend from scratch, because I have no guarantee that the colors will actually match.

All these issues can be seen on the following example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Two numerical data columns, plus one for the hue
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": np.random.random(20),
     "B": np.random.random(20),
     "C": ["c", "C"] * 10
    })

# figure with 2 subplots
(fig, [ax1, ax2]) = plt.subplots(2, 1)

# passing ax1 to sns.kdeplot
sns.kdeplot(data=data, x="A", hue="C", ax=ax1)
# passing and getting ax2
ax2 = sns.kdeplot(data=data, x="B", hue="C", ax=ax2)

# Extracting handles and labels from the axes legends
# (Those are all empty lists. Where is the info I need?)
(handles_1, labels_1) = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
(handles_2, labels_2) = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()

# Setting a global legend based on the data
fig.legend(labels=data["C"].unique(), loc="upper right")

# Setting another global legend
# based on extracted handles and labels
fig.legend(handles=handles_1, labels=labels_1, loc="center right")

# Displaying debugging info in the title
plt.suptitle(f"ax1 legend: {len(labels_1)}, ax2 legend: {len(labels_1)} labels")
plt.savefig("legend_issues.png")
```

This results in the following figure:

[image: kdeplot displays legend but axes have empty legends]

Is there a bug or do I look at the wrong place for legend handles and labels?

Comment: The easiest way to create this kind of plot is creating a FacetGrid via `sns.displot(kind='kde', ...)`.  Seaborn needs the data in long form.  E.g. `sns.displot(data=data.melt(id_vars=['C']), kind='kde', x='value', row='variable', hue='C', height=3, aspect=4)`.  (As an aside, to have a consistent order, you can change column 'C' to `pd.Categorical(...)`)

Comment: @JohanC In my real use case, I have one column with a variable taking values from 1 to 36, and I want to have a 6 x 6 array of subplots, where the data is subsetted based on this variable. So I would have rows and lines both used with the same variable somehow.

Comment: Also, in my real use case, I do use categoricals for the variable used for hue, but this doesn't seem to avoid the issue whereby the figure legend has inverted colors with respect to the individual axis legends.

Comment: Then use `col='variable'` and `col_wrap=6`, instead of `row=`

Comment: Although `sns.displot(...)` would be the recommended route, you can also do `handles = ax1.legend_.legendHandles; labels = [t.get_text() for t in ax1.legend_.texts]`, create your figure legend from those, and then call `ax1.legend_.remove()`.

Comment: @JohanC getting info from the `legend_` attributes of the axes as you suggested works. Thanks. If you make it an answer, I'm willing to accept it as a solution to my issue. I will also try to make a distplot.

Comment: I tried the `displot` (and not `distplot`, as I erroneously wrote in my previous comment, and it does the work, thanks. Note: to access the individual axes for customization (for instance to constrain x limits): `g = sns.displot(...); for ax in g.axes.flatten(): a.set_xlim(0, 1)` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43388676/1878788)